# Action executing twice when middleware is added Slim framework

Tags: php, routes, slim

I'm building a simple app based on the excellent Slim 4 Tutorial https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html

The structure is still fairly similar to the tutorial.

Every time I call any of my endpoints using Postman it executes my Actions twice (ie: \App\Action\UserGetAction) for a Get. I can confirm this is happening in my logs.

if I comment out the AuthMiddleware file in config/middleware.php the duplicate action stops happening.

Any ideas?

I have created my own Auth middleware and added it in the config/middleware.php file:

```
use Selective\BasePath\BasePathMiddleware;
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware;
use SlimSession\Helper;
use App\Factory\SessionFactory;
use App\Factory\AuthMiddleware;

return function (App $app) {
    // Parse json, form data and xml
    $app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();

    // Add the Slim built-in routing middleware
    $app->addRoutingMiddleware();

    $app->add(BasePathMiddleware::class); 

    // Catch exceptions and errors
    $app->add(ErrorMiddleware::class);

    $app->add(AuthMiddleware::class); // <--- here
  
    $loggerFactory = $app->getContainer()->get(\App\Factory\LoggerFactory::class);
    $logger = $loggerFactory->addFileHandler('error.log')->createInstance('error');

    $errorMiddleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true, $logger);

};
```

for simplicity I have stripped out pretty much everything in the AuthMiddleware:

```
namespace App\Factory;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface as RequestHandler;
use Slim\Psr7\Response;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Exception;
use App\Factory\LoggerFactory;



class AuthMiddleware
{


  /**
    * @var LoggerInterface
    */
   private $logger;

  public function __construct(LoggerFactory $logger)
  {
      $this->logger = $logger
            ->addFileHandler('user_edit.log')
            ->addConsoleHandler()
            ->createInstance('user_edit');
  }




    /**
     * Example middleware invokable class
     *
     * @param  ServerRequest  $request PSR-7 request
     * @param  RequestHandler $handler PSR-15 request handler
     *
     * @return Response
     */




    public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response
    {


        $response = $handler->handle($request);
        $headers = $request->getHeaders();


        $eauth = $headers["Authorization"][0];

        $this->logger->info($eauth);




        return $handler->handle($request);


    }




} //Class
```

here are my routes in config/routes.php:

```
    $app->post('/users', \App\Action\UserCreateAction::class);
    $app->map(['PUT', 'PATCH'],'/users/{id}[/{system}]', \App\Action\UserUpdateAction::class);
    $app->delete('/users/{id}[/{system}]', \App\Action\UserDeleteAction::class);
    $app->get('/users/{id}[/{system}]', \App\Action\UserGetAction::class);
    $app->get('/extid/{id}[/{system}]', \App\Action\ExtidGetAction::class);
```

I have confirmed that I'm only running $app-run() once --- at the end of my index.php

```
require __DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php';

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is error in `__invoke` method of your middleware.

You call handler queue twice:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response
{
    // here you call handler queue first time
    // so you get response
    $response = $handler->handle($request); 
    $headers = $request->getHeaders();

    $eauth = $headers["Authorization"][0];

    $this->logger->info($eauth);

    // here you call handle queue for the second time 
    // so you get the second duplicated version of response
    // this is the reason why you actions called twice
    return $handler->handle($request);
}
```

One of the solutions is below:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response
{
    // here you call handler queue first time
    // so you get response
    $response = $handler->handle($request); 
    $headers = $request->getHeaders();

    $eauth = $headers["Authorization"][0];

    $this->logger->info($eauth);

    // return response you already have
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: this worked! thank you.  that was the exact issue.